# Why does the ml5 DoodleNet model always say it identified the image as camouflage with 10.34% confidence?

Tags: javascript, html, machine-learning

I'm working on a website that classifies user drawn images using the ml5 doodleNet model. However, whenever I click the submit button it always says it identified the image as camouflage with 10.34% confidence? When I looked into the console, all result and confidence values were the same for each array, meaning the ml5 model may not have been working? I'm not sure how to fix it.
Here's the script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="left" id="resultContainer" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Your Drawing</h1>
        <img id="Drawing" alt="Your Drawing" width="640" height="301.5">
        <h2>The Machine Learning Model classified it as <span id="classificationResult"></span></h2>
    </div>
        <button id="submitButton" class="button">Submit!</button>
        <button id="refreshButton" class="button">Restart</button>
    <script>
        var notEmpty = false;
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resize();
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', startPainting);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopPainting);
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', sketch);
            window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
        });

        const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function resize() {
            ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        }

        let coord = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let paint = false;

        function getPosition(event) {
            coord.x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            coord.y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }

        function startPainting(event) {
            notEmpty = true;
            paint = true;
            getPosition(event);
        }

        function stopPainting() {
            paint = false;
        }

        function sketch(event) {
            if (event.type === 'click') {
            drawDot(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
            return;
        }

        if (!paint) return;
        ctx.beginPath();
            
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            
        ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
        

        getPosition(event);
        
        ctx.lineTo(coord.x , coord.y);
            
        ctx.stroke();

        const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
        submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit);

        function captureBox() {
            var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas");
            return canvas1.toDataURL();
        }
        let doodleClassifier;
        let resultsDiv;
        let boxURL;
        function submit() {
            if (!notEmpty) {
                alert('Draw on the canvas');
                    return;
            }
            boxURL = captureBox();
            const drawing = document.getElementById('Drawing');
            drawing.src = boxURL;
            const submitButton=document.getElementById('submitButton');
            submitButton.style.display='none';
                
            const canvasContainer = document.querySelector('.box');
            const resultContainer = document.getElementById('resultContainer');
            canvasContainer.style.display = 'none';
            resultContainer.style.display = 'block';

            doodleClassifier=ml5.imageClassifier('DoodleNet',modelReady);
        }
        function modelReady(){
            var img=document.createElement('img')
            img.src=boxURL
            doodleClassifier.classify(img,gotResults);
        }
        function gotResults(error,results){
            if(error){
                console.error(error);
                return;
            }
            /*console.log(results);
            let content=`${results[0].label} ${nf(100*results[0].confidence,2,)}`
            resultsDiv.html(content)*/
            console.log(results);
    
            const classificationResultSpan = document.getElementById('classificationResult');
            const resultLabel = results[0].label;
            const resultConfidence = (results[0].confidence * 100).toFixed(2);
            classificationResultSpan.innerText = `${resultLabel} with ${resultConfidence}% confidence`;
        }
        const refreshButton = document.getElementById('refreshButton');
        refreshButton.addEventListener('click', refresh);

        function refresh() {
            window.location.href='/draw'
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I tried the commented block but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The net model has either semi block you or the app programme your using is not reconfigurated or upgraded.

Try atoms in JavaScript perhaps and reverse your question to re-advance or re-expand the parameters to achieve the goals and outcomes you are looking for